# Powershell - Cut, combine and simplify lines in a file

Tags: .net, powershell, shell, command-line

I have a file.txt with the following lines:

```
Other lines...
...
Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.801 (x64)
Microsoft .NET CoreRuntime For CoreCon
Microsoft .NET CoreRuntime SDK
Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Targeting Pack (enu)
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU)
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Multi-Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU)
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1 Doc Redirected Targeting Pack (ENU)
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1 Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 Targeting Pack (ENU)
Microsoft .NET Framework Cumulative Intellisense Pack for Visual Studio (ENU)
Microsoft .NET Native SDK
Windows Desktop SDK
...
Etc
```

How can I turn the multiple .NET lines into one line like:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework [3.5] [4] [4.5] [4.5.1] [4.5.2] [4.6] [4.6.1] [4.7.1] [4.7.2]
```

And remove all the other .NET related lines in this block?

(Using powershell.)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You may (re) read the help topic [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative, not using ArrayList:

```
# read the file as string array
$lines = Get-Content -Path 'file.txt'
# create a regex string to capture the prefix and version
$regex    = '^(?<prefix>Microsoft \.NET Framework\s*)(?<version>[\d\.]+)'
$versions = @()
$count    = 0
$index    = -1

$result = $lines | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match $regex) {
        if ($index -lt 0) {
            # remember the index of this line
            $index = $count
            # output just the prefix for now, we will add the versions to it later
            $matches['prefix']
            $count++
        }
        # store the version in an array
        $versions += $matches['version']
    }
    else { $_ ; $count++}  # no match, simply output the line and increase $count

}

$result[$index] += ($versions | Sort-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object { '[{0}]' -f $_ }) -join ' '
```

Output:

> ```
> Other lines...
> ...
> Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.801 (x64)
> Microsoft .NET CoreRuntime For CoreCon
> Microsoft .NET CoreRuntime SDK
> Microsoft .NET Framework [3.5] [4] [4.5] [4.5.1] [4.5.2] [4.6] [4.6.1] [4.7.1] [4.7.2]
> Microsoft .NET Framework Cumulative Intellisense Pack for Visual Studio (ENU)
> Microsoft .NET Native SDK
> Windows Desktop SDK
> ...
> Etc
> ```

---

**Edit**

If you want to remove all other lines starting with `Microsoft .NET`, change the above code to:

```
# read the file as string array
$lines = Get-Content -Path 'file.txt'
# create a regex string to capture the prefix and version
$regex    = '^(?<prefix>Microsoft \.NET Framework\s*)(?<version>[\d\.]+)'
$versions = @()
$count    = 0
$index    = -1

$result = $lines | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match $regex) {
        if ($index -lt 0) {
            # remember the index of this line
            $index = $count
            # output just the prefix for now, we will add the versions to it later
            $matches['prefix']
            $count++
        }
        # store the version in an array
        $versions += $matches['version']
    }
    elseif ($_ -notlike 'Microsoft .NET*') { 
        # no match, output the line and increase $count if it does not start with "Microsoft .NET"
        $_
        $count++ 
    }   
}

$result[$index] += ($versions | Sort-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object { '[{0}]' -f $_ }) -join ' '

# output on screen
$result
```

> ```
> Other lines...
> ...
> Microsoft .NET Framework [3.5] [4] [4.5] [4.5.1] [4.5.2] [4.6] [4.6.1] [4.7.1] [4.7.2]
> Windows Desktop SDK
> ...
> Etc
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If it does not matter where in the file you want to insert the custom string, you can do the following:

```
$hash = [collections.arraylist]@()
[collections.arraylist]$out = switch -regex -file file.txt {
    'Microsoft .NET Framework (\d[\d\.]*)' {
        if ($hash -notcontains "[$($Matches[1])]") {
            [void]$hash.Add(("[{0}]" -f $Matches[1])) }
    }
    default { $_ }
}
$out,("Microsoft .NET Framework {0}" -f "$hash")
```

If the insertion point of the string matters, you will need some method to determine that line number. There are a number of ways to do this. The following reads the file once, loops through each line of the file, and tracks the line number that contains the first string match.

```
$hash = [collections.arraylist]@()
$firstIndex = 0
$data = Get-Content file.txt
[collections.arraylist]$out = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $data.count; $i++) {
    if ($data[$i] -match 'Microsoft .NET Framework (\d[\d\.]*)') {
        if (!$firstIndex) {
            $firstIndex = $i
        }
        if ($hash -notcontains "[$($Matches[1])]") {
            [void]$hash.Add(("[{0}]" -f $Matches[1]))
        }
    }
    else {
        $data[$i]
    }
}

$out.Insert($firstIndex,("Microsoft .NET Framework {0}" -f "$hash"))    
$out
```